# HTTP PUT and POST alternatives for uploading content

Tags: http, post, upload, put

Other than HTTP PUT and POST, what other methods can a web application designer use to allow users to upload content (either files or listbox text) from a page of his web app <s>to a remote server</s>?

On the same topic, I was wondering what technology/APIs does a service like Google Docs or Google Drive use? The reason I ask this is: Our Sys Admin has disabled file uploading (via Squid proxy), yet I was able to create and share a document using Google Docs / Google Drive.

Many thanks in advance,

/HS

**EDIT** Please see the **<s>strikeout</s>** above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the server in question - as the standard set of HTTP commands can be expanded, and some may not be configured/allowed. One of the common commands is "OPTIONS" that ask "what can I do".

But to answer more helpfully: you generally have two main options:

- POST (the one you probably want to user as it's nearly always avaiable
- GET. You could use GET (but I'm NOT advocating it - just saying you could you it - you should not use a GET to make changes to the server). There are problems with this approach (including size of files, manually handling the encoding etc) but it's possible if you have to go this route.

PUT it often not enabled on servers for security reasons.

More reading: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

---

Edit: if "file uploading" is prevented by proxy, have you tried encoding the POST? i.e. As opposed to sending a multipart POST, try encoding the files yourself into POST string and sending that instead? Or encode the file and split into multiple small posts and piecing them together at the other end?

---

Google Docs uses a mixture of POST and GET. POST for the updates. Google Drive I don't know.

Comment: No, I haven't tried (multipart) POST, yet. The proxy, I hear, is using external_acl_type that limits the Content-Length to a very small number to prevent any realistic file upload. I verified that I cannot even upload a small thumbnail on imgur.com, but I was able to create a document in Google Docs/Google Drive just fine. Hence, my wondering.

Comment: Use "fiddler" on windows and "Charles" on a mac to check the Google Docs traffic. You'll see a lot of activity, but there are lots of small "POST"s that would do the juicy work. Surprised Google Drive does it that way, but I've not checked. Presuamably it's to enable uploads to restart when borken, or to stop when the computer is busy. But definately sounds the way to go - but you do need control of the receiving server to write the code to peice together the receive.

Comment: Robbie, you may assume that the app developer has full control of the server. In light of this and what you've stated so far: In addition to HTTP PUT's, POST's, and even GET's, is there any other way to send stuff out of a browser? (I'm using Fedora Linux + Chrome, I'll see if Fiddler works here.)

Comment: "Out of a browser" - basically, no. Not only do you need to code the WebServer end, you also need to program the delivery (client) side. Not really an option.